# Xamarin.Forms CollectionView GridItemsLayout same height elements

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, collectionview

How do I make the `CollectionView` render all items with the same height while using a `GridItemsLayout` on iOS? It already works on Android that all elements in a row gets the same height but on iOS they are squished vertically in the center of the row.

This is how it currently looks on iOS (how it not should be..):
[image: iOS example screenshot]

And this is how it currently looks on Android (how it also should be on iOS - all elements are scaled to the same height in the same row):
[image: Android example screenshot]

As of now, this is how my XAML looks like:

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DataListView" ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" IsGrouped="False" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EntryTemplate}"
                Header="{Binding Header}" Footer="{Binding Footer}" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DarkBackgroundColor}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <!-- Span is set in OnSizeAllocated to make this "dynamic" -->
        <GridItemsLayout x:Name="GridItemsLayout" Orientation="Vertical" Span="1" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <Grid Padding="10,20">
                <Label Text="{Binding}" TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
    <CollectionView.FooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <Grid Padding="{OnPlatform iOS=20 30 20 20, Default=20}">
                <Label Text="{Binding}" TextColor="{DynamicResource LightTextColor}" FontSize="Micro" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.FooterTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

This is my entry data template XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EntryTemplate" x:DataType="data:Entry">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Red" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0">
        <Frame WidthRequest="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FlowColumnWidthConverter}, ConverterParameter=324}" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DarkerBackgroundColor}"
                BorderColor="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource ActiveToColorConverter}}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="8" Padding="10" CornerRadius="5">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnChecklistElementTapped" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Source="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource TypeToEmbeddedImageConverter}}" WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="32" Margin="4" />

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Region}" FontSize="12" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,-6,0,0" />

                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AdditionalData}" TextType="Html" FontSize="12" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Margin="0"
                        IsVisible="{Binding AdditionalData, Converter={StaticResource EmptyToVisibilityConverter}}" InputTransparent="True" />

                <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="12" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                        IsVisible="{Binding Description, Converter={StaticResource EmptyToVisibilityConverter}}" />

                <Switch Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsToggled="{Binding IsDone}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="12" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,4,0,4">
                    <controls:TintedImageButton Source="Details.png" Clicked="OnNavigateToDetailsButtonClicked" HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="32"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding Details, Converter={StaticResource EmptyToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                                HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />

                    <controls:TintedImageButton Source="Map.png" Clicked="OnNavigateToMapButtonClicked" HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="32"
                                                HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent" IsVisible="{x:Static resources:Metadata.MAP_ENABLED}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this is my code behind (where I set how many columns there should be):

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    GridItemsLayout.Span = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(width / 340d));
}
```

Anyone has an idea, why this is looks different on iOS in the first place and what I should look up to fix this problem?

Comment: Sadly I had a similar problem and was unable to find a solution with `CollectionView` in the end I resorted to using this library https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.HorizontalListView

Comment: @Bijington I was using FlowListView before but sadly it is not maintained since 3 years now and causes issue with the latest VS2019 on Windows (heavy lags on Android debugging). If this is not possible, I might just copy the FLV code in my project and adopt it myself to the latest Forms version (because I think that causes the issues there).

Comment: Have you tried to set card heigh manually ?

Comment: @FabriBertani setting a fixed height is not an option at all. This is something that needs to be dynamic. If something like this is required in a 2021 framework,(Xamarin) the framework should not exists at all.

Comment: could you give us a sample project so we can replicate the proble？

Comment: Since you are using a CollectionView, have you tried to set `HasUnevenRows = false` or `ItemSizingStrategy = ItemSizingStrategy.MeasureFirstItem`?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT everything needed is in the post above.

Comment: @Saamer that is not a solution because it would force every item to be the same size or smaller than the first one.

Comment: Ooooohh I see, so you want them to be the same height in the same row only! 
I have never heard a capability like this in native iOS. If you find any obj C/swift docs doing this, please do share

Comment: @Saamer I solved this before with https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView which does exactly that. However this causes heavy lags on VS Windows because there is a memory leak with RecycleElement.